# Python equivalent for gcloud auth print-identity-token command

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

The `gcloud auth print-identity-token` command prints an identity token for the specified account.

```
$(gcloud auth print-identity-token \
        --audiences=https://example.com \
        --impersonate-service-account my-sa@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
        --include-email)
```

How do I do the same using Python?

Comment: Is impersonation can be done outside the code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here a code sample (not so easy and well documented)

```
import google.auth.transport.requests
from google.auth.impersonated_credentials import IDTokenCredentials
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']

request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()

audience = 'my_audience'

creds, _ = google.auth.default(scopes=SCOPES)
icreds = google.auth.impersonated_credentials.Credentials(
        source_credentials=creds,
        target_principal="SA TO IMPERSONATE",
        target_scopes=SCOPES)

id = IDTokenCredentials(icreds, target_audience=audience,include_email=True)
id.refresh(request)
print(id.token)
```

Comment: What if I want to use the default credentials instead? I'm running this piece of code in a Cloud Function which already uses this SA at runtime, so I get the credentials as the default ones. If I refresh the default creds and feed them to the `IDTokenCredentials` class,  I get a `Provided Credential must be impersonated_credentials` error. How could I get this JWT from the default credentials?

Comment: Did you try to use `creds` instead of `icreds` in that line `id = IDTokenCredentials(icreds,...`

Comment: Yes, that was when the `Provided Credential must be impersonated_credentials` error message showed

Comment: I found [this](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/get-id-token#metadata-server) documentation explaining how to use the metadata server for that particular use case. Maybe it's useful for more people, so I will leave it here

Comment: Yes but.... I'm worried about that "explicit use of compute engine class". The standard libraries should detect automatically the runtime environment (especially if the metadata server is present, which mean you are on Google Cloud environment) and the IDCredential object creation should works out of the box.. Personally I consider that as a bug in the library.

Comment: I guess it doesn't work because we are using the IDTokenCredentials object of the `impersonated_credentials` module, while we are not using a impersonated credentials but the application default ones. Are you aware if it exists a different IDTokenCredentials for a non impersonated credentials? I also tried to use the token got after refreshing the default creds, but that's an access token instead of a JWT

Comment: My bad, if you want to fetch ID token without impersonation, simply use fetch_id_token https://googleapis.dev/python/google-auth/1.14.0/reference/google.oauth2.id_token.html#google.oauth2.id_token.fetch_id_token

Comment: Wow, that was easy! Thanks for sharing, I was not able to find that function